# Найти такие перестановки, чтобы сумма трёх цифр не превосходила 16

Tags: python-3.x, перестановка

Требуется расставить все ненулевые цифры по окружности (каждая цифра используется ровно 1 раз) таким образом, чтобы сумма любых трёх подряд идущих цифр не превосходила 16.

В уме я одну такую перестановку нашёл: 158267349.

Как найти на Питоне все такие перестановки?
Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: И 16 - это минимально возможная такая сумма? Уже 15 не получается?

Comment: Разумеется, 15 не получится. Сумма всех чисел от 1 до 9 равна 45. Поэтому, если в каждой тройке сумма не более 15, то она равна 15. Но тогда каждое из чисел должно быть равно стоящему от него через два. А у нас все числа попарно различны, что приводит нас к противоречию.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Находим все перестановки.
2. Ищем сумму в любой тройке цифр больше 16 в каждой перестановке
3. Делаем фильтр по этому

---

```
from itertools import permutations

a = 123456789

print(list(filter(
  lambda x: not any(sum(map(int, (x+x)[i:i+3])) > 16 for i in range(len(x))),
  map(''.join, permutations(str(a)))
)))
```

Comment: Так по окружности же числа.

Comment: Вдоль окружности расставлены все числа от 1 до 9. Например, 918726534, круг замкнулся.

Comment: Нет, не просто. Например, если перестановка такая: 591672438, то она не годится, так как 8+5+9>16.

Comment: А каким образом их добавлять?

Comment: `not any(` == `all(` с противоположным условием, так просто короче, но какой вариант понятнее - это, конечно, вопрос )

Comment: Всё равно не работает. Например, в перестановке 961582374 имеем 4+9+6>16.

Comment: @ЯнАльбертовичДененберг, обновил ответ

Answer (score 3):

вот простое решение грубым перебором, но вроде работает:

```
from itertools import permutations

for p in permutations([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]):
    c = p + p[:2]
    if all(sum(i)<17 for i in zip(c,c[1:],c[2:])):
        print(p)
```

результат:

```
(1, 5, 8, 2, 6, 7, 3, 4, 9)
(1, 6, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 4, 9)
(1, 6, 7, 3, 4, 8, 2, 5, 9)
(1, 6, 7, 3, 4, 9, 2, 5, 8)
(1, 6, 7, 3, 5, 8, 2, 4, 9)
(1, 6, 8, 2, 5, 7, 3, 4, 9)
(1, 6, 8, 2, 5, 7, 4, 3, 9)
(1, 7, 6, 3, 4, 9, 2, 5, 8)
(1, 8, 5, 2, 9, 4, 3, 6, 7)
(1, 8, 5, 2, 9, 4, 3, 7, 6)
(1, 9, 3, 4, 7, 5, 2, 8, 6)
(1, 9, 4, 2, 8, 5, 3, 7, 6)
(1, 9, 4, 3, 7, 5, 2, 8, 6)
(1, 9, 4, 3, 7, 6, 2, 8, 5)
(1, 9, 4, 3, 8, 5, 2, 7, 6)
(1, 9, 5, 2, 8, 4, 3, 7, 6)
(2, 4, 9, 1, 6, 7, 3, 5, 8)
(2, 5, 7, 3, 4, 9, 1, 6, 8)
(2, 5, 7, 4, 3, 9, 1, 6, 8)
(2, 5, 8, 1, 6, 7, 3, 4, 9)
(2, 5, 8, 1, 7, 6, 3, 4, 9)
(2, 5, 8, 3, 4, 9, 1, 6, 7)
(2, 5, 9, 1, 6, 7, 3, 4, 8)
(2, 6, 7, 3, 4, 9, 1, 5, 8)
(2, 7, 6, 1, 9, 4, 3, 8, 5)
(2, 8, 4, 3, 7, 6, 1, 9, 5)
(2, 8, 5, 1, 9, 4, 3, 7, 6)
(2, 8, 5, 3, 7, 6, 1, 9, 4)
(2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 3, 4, 7, 5)
(2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 4, 3, 7, 5)
(2, 9, 4, 3, 6, 7, 1, 8, 5)
(2, 9, 4, 3, 7, 6, 1, 8, 5)
(3, 4, 7, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9)
(3, 4, 8, 2, 5, 9, 1, 6, 7)
(3, 4, 9, 1, 5, 8, 2, 6, 7)
(3, 4, 9, 1, 6, 7, 2, 5, 8)
(3, 4, 9, 1, 6, 8, 2, 5, 7)
(3, 4, 9, 2, 5, 8, 1, 6, 7)
(3, 4, 9, 2, 5, 8, 1, 7, 6)
(3, 5, 8, 2, 4, 9, 1, 6, 7)
(3, 6, 7, 1, 8, 5, 2, 9, 4)
(3, 7, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 4)
(3, 7, 6, 1, 8, 5, 2, 9, 4)
(3, 7, 6, 1, 9, 4, 2, 8, 5)
(3, 7, 6, 1, 9, 5, 2, 8, 4)
(3, 7, 6, 2, 8, 5, 1, 9, 4)
(3, 8, 5, 2, 7, 6, 1, 9, 4)
(3, 9, 1, 6, 8, 2, 5, 7, 4)
(4, 2, 8, 5, 3, 7, 6, 1, 9)
(4, 3, 6, 7, 1, 8, 5, 2, 9)
(4, 3, 7, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9)
(4, 3, 7, 6, 1, 8, 5, 2, 9)
(4, 3, 7, 6, 1, 9, 5, 2, 8)
(4, 3, 7, 6, 2, 8, 5, 1, 9)
(4, 3, 8, 5, 2, 7, 6, 1, 9)
(4, 3, 9, 1, 6, 8, 2, 5, 7)
(4, 7, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 3)
(4, 8, 2, 5, 9, 1, 6, 7, 3)
(4, 9, 1, 5, 8, 2, 6, 7, 3)
(4, 9, 1, 6, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3)
(4, 9, 1, 6, 7, 3, 5, 8, 2)
(4, 9, 1, 6, 8, 2, 5, 7, 3)
(4, 9, 2, 5, 8, 1, 6, 7, 3)
(4, 9, 2, 5, 8, 1, 7, 6, 3)
(5, 1, 9, 4, 3, 7, 6, 2, 8)
(5, 2, 7, 6, 1, 9, 4, 3, 8)
(5, 2, 8, 4, 3, 7, 6, 1, 9)
(5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 3, 4, 7)
(5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 4, 3, 7)
(5, 2, 9, 4, 3, 6, 7, 1, 8)
(5, 2, 9, 4, 3, 7, 6, 1, 8)
(5, 3, 7, 6, 1, 9, 4, 2, 8)
(5, 7, 3, 4, 9, 1, 6, 8, 2)
(5, 7, 4, 3, 9, 1, 6, 8, 2)
(5, 8, 1, 6, 7, 3, 4, 9, 2)
(5, 8, 1, 7, 6, 3, 4, 9, 2)
(5, 8, 2, 4, 9, 1, 6, 7, 3)
(5, 8, 2, 6, 7, 3, 4, 9, 1)
(5, 8, 3, 4, 9, 1, 6, 7, 2)
(5, 9, 1, 6, 7, 3, 4, 8, 2)
(6, 1, 8, 5, 2, 9, 4, 3, 7)
(6, 1, 9, 3, 4, 7, 5, 2, 8)
(6, 1, 9, 4, 2, 8, 5, 3, 7)
(6, 1, 9, 4, 3, 7, 5, 2, 8)
(6, 1, 9, 4, 3, 8, 5, 2, 7)
(6, 1, 9, 5, 2, 8, 4, 3, 7)
(6, 2, 8, 5, 1, 9, 4, 3, 7)
(6, 3, 4, 9, 2, 5, 8, 1, 7)
(6, 7, 1, 8, 5, 2, 9, 4, 3)
(6, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 4, 9, 1)
(6, 7, 3, 4, 8, 2, 5, 9, 1)
(6, 7, 3, 4, 9, 1, 5, 8, 2)
(6, 7, 3, 4, 9, 2, 5, 8, 1)
(6, 7, 3, 5, 8, 2, 4, 9, 1)
(6, 8, 2, 5, 7, 3, 4, 9, 1)
(6, 8, 2, 5, 7, 4, 3, 9, 1)
(7, 1, 8, 5, 2, 9, 4, 3, 6)
(7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 4, 9, 1, 6)
(7, 3, 4, 8, 2, 5, 9, 1, 6)
(7, 3, 4, 9, 1, 5, 8, 2, 6)
(7, 3, 4, 9, 1, 6, 8, 2, 5)
(7, 3, 4, 9, 2, 5, 8, 1, 6)
(7, 3, 5, 8, 2, 4, 9, 1, 6)
(7, 4, 3, 9, 1, 6, 8, 2, 5)
(7, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 3, 4)
(7, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 4, 3)
(7, 6, 1, 8, 5, 2, 9, 4, 3)
(7, 6, 1, 9, 4, 2, 8, 5, 3)
(7, 6, 1, 9, 4, 3, 8, 5, 2)
(7, 6, 1, 9, 5, 2, 8, 4, 3)
(7, 6, 2, 8, 5, 1, 9, 4, 3)
(7, 6, 3, 4, 9, 2, 5, 8, 1)
(8, 1, 6, 7, 3, 4, 9, 2, 5)
(8, 1, 7, 6, 3, 4, 9, 2, 5)
(8, 2, 4, 9, 1, 6, 7, 3, 5)
(8, 2, 5, 7, 3, 4, 9, 1, 6)
(8, 2, 5, 7, 4, 3, 9, 1, 6)
(8, 2, 5, 9, 1, 6, 7, 3, 4)
(8, 2, 6, 7, 3, 4, 9, 1, 5)
(8, 3, 4, 9, 1, 6, 7, 2, 5)
(8, 4, 3, 7, 6, 1, 9, 5, 2)
(8, 5, 1, 9, 4, 3, 7, 6, 2)
(8, 5, 2, 7, 6, 1, 9, 4, 3)
(8, 5, 2, 9, 4, 3, 6, 7, 1)
(8, 5, 2, 9, 4, 3, 7, 6, 1)
(8, 5, 3, 7, 6, 1, 9, 4, 2)
(8, 6, 1, 9, 3, 4, 7, 5, 2)
(8, 6, 1, 9, 4, 3, 7, 5, 2)
(9, 1, 5, 8, 2, 6, 7, 3, 4)
(9, 1, 6, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 4)
(9, 1, 6, 7, 3, 4, 8, 2, 5)
(9, 1, 6, 7, 3, 5, 8, 2, 4)
(9, 1, 6, 8, 2, 5, 7, 3, 4)
(9, 1, 6, 8, 2, 5, 7, 4, 3)
(9, 2, 5, 8, 1, 6, 7, 3, 4)
(9, 2, 5, 8, 1, 7, 6, 3, 4)
(9, 3, 4, 7, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1)
(9, 4, 2, 8, 5, 3, 7, 6, 1)
(9, 4, 3, 6, 7, 1, 8, 5, 2)
(9, 4, 3, 7, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1)
(9, 4, 3, 7, 6, 1, 8, 5, 2)
(9, 4, 3, 7, 6, 2, 8, 5, 1)
(9, 4, 3, 8, 5, 2, 7, 6, 1)
(9, 5, 2, 8, 4, 3, 7, 6, 1)
```